# Checking whether an object is a "listdiff" in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, difference-lists

> A listdiff is a pair whose car is L and whose cdr is eq? to either L, or to (cdr L), or to (cdr (cdr L))), etc. The cdr of a listdiff need not be a list; it may be any object.
>
> A listdiff D represents the prefix of (car D) that precedes (cdr D). For example, suppose ils is the improper list (a e i o u . y). Then (cons ils ils) returns an empty listdiff, (cons ils (cdr (cdr ils))) returns a listdiff with the same elements as the list (a e), and (cons (cdr ils) 'y) returns a listdiff with the same elements as (e i o u). Conversely, neither (cons '() ils) nor (cons ils (append '(a e i o u) 'y)) returns a listdiff.

I want to create the following procedure on Racket:

> (listdiff? obj)
>
> Returns #t if obj is a listdiff, #f otherwise.

Can anyone give me indications to do it?

Comment: For what it's worth, this appears to be [a homework assignment](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/fall08/cs131/hw/hw5.html) (that's from 2008, so perhaps a professor is reusing assignments, or you're working through some exercises).  In either case, you should attribute the sources.

Comment: The whole concept of "listdiff" seems a bit over-engineered.  It'd be easier to say "a listdiff is a cons whose car is a list L and whose cdr is a tail of L".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a skeleton you can use.

```
(define (listdiff? pair)
  (define l (car pair))      ; l
  (define needle (cdr pair)) ; needle is what to look for in l
  (define (search haystack)
    ;; #t when haystack looks the same as needle
    ;; #f if haystackk is the empty list
    ;; otherwise recurse to (cdr haystack)
    )

  (search l))
```